# Young Rhubard plant with yellow leaf

Tags: leaves, harvesting, rhubarb

Planted my first rhubarb plant last year. It has about 7 stalks this year. All were green but one of the largest leaves near the base has just turned yellow. I definitely think we’ve over watered it the last week or so, but because it’s such a young plant, should I harvest that one stalk or rather leave it?[image]

Comment: A photo would  be very helpful as well as knowing whether the plant is in the ground or in a pot,and what part of the word you're in.

Comment: I’m in Vienna, Austria

Comment: The plant is in a pot as we have a ‘rooftop’ garden with very little top soil, about 5-10cm before you hit a stoney granular layer

Comment: I;m  very sorry to say that it is next to impossible to grow a rhubarb  plant successfully in a container. I even tried the largest container I could find (1.5 metres wide by 1.5 metres deep) and it still didn't work, though mine was a very large crown. .Maybe if you get someone to make a container that's bigger than the one I mention, it might be successful.

Comment: Would you recommend removing the yellow leafed stalk though or is the plant too young for that still?

Comment: You can remove it - by the looks of it, its just going to die  back anyway.